# Highcharts isn't displaying the data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am adding series' after I load the data from my API. The issue is that the series data is not being displayed. I have the same format for the data as if you just added the series right when you make the chart. I have checked my JSON and all the data coming through and all of that is fine.

Code:

```
var overallGraph;

$(document).ready(function() {

    updateGraph();

    function updateGraph() {
        $.post('../api/overall-lookup.php?d=4', function(json) {
            var guildData = [];
            var textCData = [];
            var offiUData = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                var data = json['lookup-results'][i];
                guildData.push(data['guilds']);
                textCData.push(data['text_channels']);
                offiUData.push(data['official_users']);
            }

            overallGraph.addSeries({'name': 'guilds', 'data': guildData}, true);
            overallGraph.addSeries({'name': 'text channels', 'data': textCData}, true);
            overallGraph.addSeries({'name': 'official users', 'data': offiUData}, true);
        });
    }

    overallGraph = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Overall Data For FlareBot',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            title : {
                text: 'Date'
            }  
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Amount'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    });
});
```

Output:
[image: output]

JSON

```
{
  "code": 300,
  "lookup-results": [
    {
      "date": "2017-01-01",
      "guilds": "759",
      "text_channels": "4320",
      "official_users": "79"
    },
    {
      "date": "2016-12-31",
      "guilds": "756",
      "text_channels": "4409",
      "official_users": "81"
    },
    {
      "date": "2016-12-30",
      "guilds": "717",
      "text_channels": "4225",
      "official_users": "82"
    },
    {
      "date": "2016-12-29",
      "guilds": "700",
      "text_channels": "4137",
      "official_users": "78"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your json here?

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/bNkhNwf3 @morganfree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have strings in data and you need numbers, so you have to convert string to number.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        var data = json['lookup-results'][i];
        guildData.push(Number(data['guilds']));
        textCData.push(Number(data['text_channels']));
        offiUData.push(Number(data['official_users']));
    }
```